# Cómo hacer responsive una pagina web?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Tengo que hacer mi web responsive y no se como hacerlo, intento pero nada me funciona.

Estuve mirando videos en youtube y no encontré la respuesta, probé con `@media screen` pero no estoy seguro de donde debo ponerlo y si es correcto utilizarlo.

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco mucho!

Este es el código:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: url(/img/leadspace.jpg);
  height: 450px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.home {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.titulo {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 30px;
}

.contenido {
  text-align: center;
}

.contenido p {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

#general {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1550px;
  height: 800px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

.parrafo1 {
  margin: auto;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <section>
    <h1 class="titulo">Ciberseguridad</h1>
    <div class="contenido">
      <p>¿Qué es y para qué sirve la ciberseguridad?</p>
      <p>Te explicamos como protegerte en internet y proteger tu información confidencial </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</header>
<body>
  <section class="home">
    <div id="general">
      <h1>¿Que es la ciberseguridad?</h1>
      <div class="parrafo1">
        <p> La ciberseguridad es el conjunto de procedimientos y herramientas que se implementan para proteger la información que se genera y procesa a través de computadoras, servidores, dispositivos móviles, redes y sistemas electrónicos.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como se ve? como se deberia ver?

Comment: Si tienes un problema, edita la pregunta. Si buscas que te enseñen a hacer una página responsive (que se adapta a cualquier pantalla y se vea bien en ella) deberías mirar/leer un tutorial o seguir una guía. Por ejemplo este: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/responsive-web-design-how-to-make-a-website-look-good-on-phones-and-tablets/

Answer (score 0):

Una página responsiva es básicamente (muy básicamente) un manejo de tamaño no fijo, por ejemplo

```
#general {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1550px;
  height: 800px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

Tendrías que cambiar Width por máx-width 1550px y ponerle width 100% y las medias query se agregan a la parte final del archivo css (por su lectura en cascada principalmente) y se usa para casos específicos. Por ejemplo mantienes la base que puse al principio del párrafo y en la media query le pones <700px un width de 70%

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .general {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```